# Artisan::call() with confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to call a artisan command programmatically with Artisan::call(). The problem is that the command contains a confirmation question.

```
if ($this->confirm('Do you wish to continue? [yes|no]')) { }
```

Is there any way to confirm this question?

Comment: Hm, `expect` libraries usually would work... Or you could fiddle around with `setInputStream()` on the dialog.

Comment: `setInputStream()` seems to be what i want but i'm uncertain how i could use it with artisan. I'll keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I dislike delving in the badly documented innards of Laravel.. there seems to be an `Application::setHelpSet()` function you probably want, but I gave up searching there.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your command with an option to bypass the confirmation:

```
protected $signature = 'my:command {--force}';

public function handle()
{
  $force = $this->option('force');
  if ($force || $this->confirm('Do you wish to continue? [yes|no]')) { }
}
```

If you then call your command programmatically with the force option it will skip the confirmation:

```
Artisan::call('my:command', [
  '--force' => true,
])
```