# Interact with Artisan command programmatically

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan

First of all, the question is kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664374/artisancall-with-confirmation), but unfortunately, it does not have an answer.

Consider having an **interactive** command like the following:

```php
class SayHello extends Command
{
   protected $signature = 'say:hello';

   public handle()
   {
        $name = $this->ask('Your name');
        
        $this->info('Hello, ' . $name . '!');
   }
}
```

The question is: How to call this command programmatically (in controller, job, tinker, etc.) and answer the question using code (without real-time interaction)?

PS: I already know I can call an artisan command using the [`Artisan::call()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) method. I want to know how to handle interaction (questions, choices, etc.)

Comment: @KhaldounAlHalabi Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

`Artisan::call` can be used to execute commands programmatically. Eg:

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
$name = "John Doe";
Artisan::call('say:hello', [
    'name' => $name,
]);
//OR
Artisan::call('say:hello John');
//AND
Artisan::output(); //gives you the output
```

Call method's first argument is command signature and the second is an array of parameters.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: Your solution would work if the name were an argument. My question is about interactive commands that ask questions and present choices.

Comment: @TheSETJ yeah looks like I missed `Artisan::output()`, which gives you the output. You can build your logic from there. I assume you would have preconfigured options to react to based on the output. But, very curious what you are building, mixing console and web/other. Perhaps you could have service classes to reuse in console and web. Apologies if I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it does. BTW thanks for your time and effort.